# delegate problem, name doesn't exist in current context?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I work with my first delegate, but i have a little problem, could you help me please.

I work with a consoleApp in dotnet core 3.1

I tried to modify the access identifier with private in public but without result:

```
using System;

namespace _29_Delegate_Et_Lambda
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Working on Delegate");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");

        double resultatAddition;

        resultatAddition = ExecuterOperationDeMath(Additionner, 123, 43);

        Console.WriteLine(resultatAddition);
    }

    public class Calcul
    {
        //  1-  Creation delegate:
        delegate double OperationDeMath(double a, double b);

        // 2-  Declaration methode Additionner du meme type que le delegate.
        public static double Additionner(double a, double b) { return a + b; }

        // 2-  Declaration d'une methode Soustraction du meme type que le delegate.
        static double Soustraction(double a, double b) => a + b;

        //  3-  Utilisation delegate:
        static double ExecuterOperationDeMath(OperationDeMath operationAEffectuer, double a, double b)
        {
            return operationAEffectuer(a, b);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you say a bit about why you decided to make a public nested class? This is not wrong exactly, but it is *strange*. Normally if you wanted a nested class it would be a private implementation detail.

Comment: @Eric Lippert 
I use a calcul class to dissociate the Program class from mine.

Comment: Right, but you put the calculation class *inside* the program class, which does not disassociate it; it strongly associates it with the program class!

Comment: @ Eric Lippert 
Yes you are right to notice it to me, it is indeed a mistake on my part.
Thanks Eric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve this. But first, make the following chages:

1. Class `Calcul` should be `public static` and should not/need not be nested inside class `Program`
2. Make the delegate public to match the accessability of the method
3. Make `Soustraction` `public static` too.

The 2 ways to solve it are either

a. add `using static Calcul` to the top of your file. This opens up all the static methods of that class with your exact current syntax. or;

b. Use the class name before each call to a static method ie `Calcul.ExecuterOperationDeMath`

Live examples:
 a. https://dotnetfiddle.net/u78cOy
 b. https://dotnetfiddle.net/2vRSnm

Comment: Thank you very much @Jamiec 
Your answers are very explicit :-)

Answer (score 0):

What exact error do you get? To access a static method you have to specify the class name. And all the relevant methods need to be `public` in the class.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Working on Delegate");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");

        double resultatAddition;

        resultatAddition = Calcul.ExecuterOperationDeMath(Calcul.Additionner, 123, 43);

        Console.WriteLine(resultatAddition);
    }

    public class Calcul
    {
        //  1-  Creation delegate:
        public delegate double OperationDeMath(double a, double b);

        // 2-  Declaration methode Additionner du meme type que le delegate.
        public static double Additionner(double a, double b) { return a + b; }

        // 2-  Declaration d'une methode Soustraction du meme type que le delegate.
        public static double Soustraction(double a, double b) => a + b;

        //  3-  Utilisation delegate:
        public static double ExecuterOperationDeMath(OperationDeMath operationAEffectuer, double a, double b)
        {
            return operationAEffectuer(a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9RUXHc

These problems are about access modifiers, and don't have much, if anything, to do with delegates really.

N.B. As others have mentioned, it's also unclear why the `Calcul` class is nested within `Program`. That's relatively unusual and usually unnecessary. But it's not directly relevant to the question you asked.

Comment: The imbrication calcul class is my bad, thank to you.